# SpringBoot, manual control of two data sources, transaction failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions

I'm using SpringBoot 2.1.8.RELEASE, I have two datasource, I manually control transactions.
transaction (marked"@Primary") works. But, transaction marked another datasource  is not working properly.
Do you have any suggestions?

Maven configuration is as below

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

other omit...
```

One datasource configure as below:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"com.XXX.XXXX.mapper","com.XXX.XXX.common.mapper"},sqlSessionFactoryRef = "masterSqlSessionFactory")
public class ProductDataSourceConfig {
    static final String MAPPER_LOCATION = "classpath:mybatis/MYSQL/*.xml";


    @Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.product")
    public DataSource masterDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "masterTransactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager masterTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(masterDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = "masterSqlSessionFactory")

    public SqlSessionFactory masterSqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("masterDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource)
            throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(masterDataSource);
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
                .getResources(ProductDataSourceConfig.MAPPER_LOCATION));
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}
```

another  datasource configure as below:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.XXX.XXX.mapperTest",sqlSessionFactoryRef = "secondSqlSessionFactory")
public class TestDataSourceConfig {
    static final String MAPPER_LOCATION = "classpath:mybatis/TESTMYSQL/*.xml";

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.test")
    public DataSource clusterDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager clusterTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(clusterDataSource());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "secondSqlSessionFactory")
    public SqlSessionFactory clusterSqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource clusterDataSource)
            throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(clusterDataSource);
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
                .getResources(TestDataSourceConfig.MAPPER_LOCATION));
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}
```

When configured as follows, submit as expected(in the "@Primary" db,record inserted ).

```
@Autowired
DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager;

DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setTimeout(500);
def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

TransactionStatus transactionStatus = dataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(def);

insertTmemberEnterRecord(bean);

dataSourceTransactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
```

But the following configuration as follows, submit is not work(No data inserted into table),also no error message.

```
@Qualifier("masterTransactionManager")
@Autowired
DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager;
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setTimeout(500);
def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

TransactionStatus transactionStatus = dataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(def);

insertTmemberEnterRecord(bean);

dataSourceTransactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
The reason is that the corresponding mapper file should also be used.